# Ubuntu, postfix, dovecot mail server cannot configure with Outlook or Thunderbird mail client

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, mail-server

I have successfully configured my email server with digital-ocean ubuntu 18.04 LEMP droplet and everything work fine so far. I can send & receive email and also successfully configured with round-cube webmail client. I used Mailgun as an SMTP relay.

But when I tried to connect to a mailbox in my mail server through outlook or Thunderbird, it keep on saying that the client failed to find the settings for the account. I tried to do the configuration manually and still giving me the same error.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciable.

**Output of** `postconf -n`

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.myservername.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = myservername.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.mailgun.org]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:postmaster@mail.myservername.com:999999999-000000000000-9999999
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_mailbox_domains = myservername.com
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

**Output of** `dovecot -n`

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
protocols = " imap sieve"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
}
service imap {
  process_limit = 1024
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
```

`sudo nmap your-server-ip` gives following output :

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
80/tcp  open   http
443/tcp closed https
587/tcp open   submission
```